# How to create a yes no filter option on custom product option shopify liquid

Tags: filter, boolean, shopify, liquid, optional-parameters

I have products with an option set of initials, so a-z on the frontend category filter. This is obviously very long when expanded and was wondering if it could be set to a yes/no boolean instead?

Edit. The below image is what i'm looking to duplicate and have attached the code for that. I'm guessing I could copy but change the param name? but not sure what the param name would be.

[image]

```
{%- if filter.param_name == 'filter.v.availability' -%}
        <div class="filter-group filter-group--availability">
          <div class="filter-toggle filter-toggle--inline">
            <span class="filter-toggle__group-label">{{ 'collections.filtering.out_of_stock_label' | t }}</span>
            <div class="filter-toggle__options">
              
              <label class="filter-toggle__input-label">
                <input class="filter-toggle__input"
                  id="Filter-{{ filter.param_name }}-1"
                  type="radio"
                  name="{{ filter.param_name }}"
                  value=""
                  {% if filter.active_values == empty %}checked{% endif %}>
                <span class="filter-toggle__input-label-text">{{ 'collections.filtering.show_label' | t }}</span>
              </label>
              <label class="filter-toggle__input-label" id="second-filter-btn">
                <input class="filter-toggle__input"
                  id="Filter-{{ filter.param_name }}-2"
                  type="radio"
                  name="{{ filter.param_name }}"
                  value="1"
                  {% if filter.active_values != empty and filter.active_values.first.value == '1' %}checked{% endif %}>
                  <span class="filter-toggle__input-label-text">{{ 'collections.filtering.hide_label' | t }}</span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      {%- else -%}
```

Comment: Could you show at least the expected result? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @FabioFilippi I have updated the ticket with an example. Would it be a case of duplicating that code and changing the param name? If so do you know how i would find the param name? cheers